# IIS 10 url rewrite with reverse proxy 404 errors

Tags: django, flask, url, redirect, iis

I am currently running 2 python applications on IIS 10.

- Django app bind to https://mydomain.ca/
- Flask app bind to http://localhost:8000

The default page for the flask app is http://localhost:8000/databases

I am trying to url rewrite https://mydomain.ca/datatools to my flask app. I am receiving my flask app's error 404 page each time. Here are the rules in my `web.config` file:

```
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^datatools$" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://mydomain.ca/datatools/" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="Reverse Proxy" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^datatools/$" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:8000/databases/" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^datatools/*(.*)$" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:8000/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please try using FRT to trace rewrite rules, you can see how the rules are used internally. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules